# Change color of div elements (box) based on an input value

Tags: javascript

I need to display 3 boxes next to each other. Based on an input value the color of the box need to be changed. For example: the first box should display red if a number is in range of (1-3) & all other boxes should be gray; similarly if a number is in range of (4-6) then second box should be yellow while 1st and 3rd box should be gray; third box should be green if the number is in range of (7-9).

The idea is basically to display rating. So Red (1-3), Yellow (4-6) and Green (7-9). So if rating for innovation contains value 2 then first box should be red.

I tried by following way:

```js
var num = 4;
var strColorPairs = Array({
  'position': 0,
  'color': 'red'
}, {
  'position': 1,
  'color': 'yellow'
}, {
  'position': 2,
  'color': 'green'
});

var position = checkPosition(num);


colorBox(position);

function colorBox(position) {
  var divList = document.getElementsByClassName('ratingBox');
  var i, n = divList.length;
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    curContent = divList[i].children[0].id;
    for (j = 0; j < strColorPairs.length; j++) {
      if (strColorPairs[j].position == curContent)
        divList[i].style.backgroundColor = strColorPairs[j].color;
    }
  }
}

function checkPosition(num) {
  var position;
  if (isInRange(num, 1, 3)) {
    position = 0;
  } else if (isInRange(num, 4, 6)) {
    position = 1;
  } else if (isInRange(num, 7, 9)) {
    position = 2;
  }
  return position;
}

function isInRange(num, min, max) {
  return num >= min && num <= max;
}
```

```html
Rating for innovation
<div id="0" class="ratingBox"></div>
<div id="1" class="ratingBox"></div>
<div id="2" class="ratingBox"></div>
```

But i am missing the right logic here. Could you please help me how to do it in a right way.

Comment: Please add [mcve] this example is not complete, for example you are trying to access children of the rating-box and the example has none.

Comment: strColorPairs = Array()  but then you put key/value pairs in it. So length will be 0

Comment: What output do you expect? What output are getting instead? `But I am missing the right logic` Right logic for What? Why is your existing logic wrong?

Comment: Also `divList[i].children[0]` will return `undefined`.

Comment: @CBroe Actually it turns out using Array() it does have length=3 ... hmm

Comment: actually i am not sure how to proceed with it, so i had just a rough idea and put it here. The output should be like 3 boxes next to each other. If an input value is 2 then the backgroundcolor of first box should be red,

Comment: of course, it's just 3 objects ... I gotta read better....zzzz

Comment: @user596502 you need to look into event handlers for your input (so that it can determine when to "run" the code that checks what box/color is active). Run with devtools to see any errors and more importantly step through your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var num =1; 
var strColorPairs = Array(
                            {'position' : 0, 'color' : 'red'},
                            {'position' : 1, 'color' : 'yellow'},
                            {'position' : 2, 'color' : 'green'}
                        );

var position = checkPosition(num);


colorBox(position);
 function colorBox(position)
    {
        var divList = document.getElementsByClassName('ratingBox');
        var i, n = divList.length;
        curContent = divList[position].id;
        console.log(curContent);
        for (i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            
            for (j=0; j<strColorPairs.length; j++)
            {
                if (strColorPairs[j].position == curContent){
                    divList[curContent].style.backgroundColor  = strColorPairs[j].color;
                    }
                else {divList[i].style.backgroundColor  = 'gray'}
            }
        }
    }

function checkPosition(num){
 var position;
   if(isInRange(num,1,3))
     {
      position=0;
     }
     else if(isInRange(num,4,6))
     {
      position=1;
     }
     else if(isInRange(num,7,9))
     {
      position=2;
     }
     return position;
 }

function isInRange(num,min,max){
    return num >= min && num <= max;
 }
```

```css
.ratingBox{
width:50px;height:50px;}
```

```html
Rating for innovation 
     <div id="0" class="ratingBox"></div>
     <div id="1" class="ratingBox"></div>
     <div id="2" class="ratingBox"></div>
```

try

Comment: @user596502 check the mistakes

Comment: Yeah i made some mistakes while getting the id in divList , and also assiging in the curContent. Thanks! @Durga is there any other better way to achieve the same result or do u have any suggestion for refactoring of this code.

Comment: @user596502 check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/durga598/afLqfy1u/2/)